# HTTPS Grails application URL

Tags: grails, https

My Grails app runs over HTTPS and in `Config.groovy` I've set:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "https://localhost:8443/foo"
    }
}
```

When I execute `grails run-app` to start the app in dev mode, the last message printed on the console is:

> Server running. Browse to `http://localhost:8082/foo`

If I accidentally click on this URL to access the application, I get various errors due to the same-origin security policy (because `https://localhost:8443` is a different host to `http://localhost:8082`).

Why is Grails prompting me to access my app via `http://localhost:8082/foo` when I've set `grails.serverURL = "https://localhost:8443/foo"`

### Update

I changed the startup command to `grails run-app -https` and the last message printed on the console is now:

> Server running. Browse to `http://localhost:8082/foo` or `https://localhost:8443/foo`

Why am I given the option of either HTTP or HTTPS, rather than just the latter? Also, I get this exception during startup:

```
http11.Http11Protocol Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8443
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:407)
```

I've checked if port 8443 is in use before I run this command (it isn't), but the server seems to startup despite this exception, so this is not a major concern.

Answer (score 3):

Replace grails.serverURL with the code below.

Its possible to set the port with the following [system properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html):

```
grails.server.port = 8082
```

That should work for both http and https. To configure for just one:

```
grails.server.port.https = 8082
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get it running on port 8443 on HTTPS. I tried removing `grails.serverURL` and adding just `grails.server.port.https = 8443`, but it still prompts me to access it via `http://localhost:8082/foo`

Comment: But what is running on https? From the docs listed above:
Arguments:

https - Start an HTTPS server (on port 8443 by default) alongside the main server. Just to be clear, the application will be accessible via HTTPS and HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `--https` parameter to run-app for Grails to respond to HTTPS and HTTP in development mode. At least according to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html).

Try using

```
grails run-app --https
```

Further more, the `grails.serverURL` is typically used by taglibs and plugins, and not the launching process as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ssl port you want to run you application on via https in BuildConfig.groovy. You can add the following to your BuildConfig.groovy

`//You can specify another port here to get rid of your startup exception
grails.server.port.https="8443"

grails.server.host="localhost"`

Then try **grails run-app -https** and you should be able to run your app on the ssl port you defined or the default 8080 port